# USB A 2.0 +5V bus interfering with Vsys?

Tags: voltage, usb, usb-device, usb-host

I want to have a USB connector on my PCB that will act only as host for joysticks. It will be a USB2.0  A connector. The voltage supplied for this is from +5V_Vsys. My question is what happens when a user will plug in this connector  a PC port wich will have also a +5V voltage across is right? The input voltage will not mess my Vsys? should i have some diodes on my line? i dont want to implement an OTG function because my PCB dont need to be slave by USB A 2.0. 
[image: Schematics of PCB]

Comment: Naked "Male-to-male" USB cables are forbidden for this very reason - you could damage the PC (if it wasn't turned on). Note that your output cap on the VBUS line is at least one order of magnitude too small for a *host* port.

Comment: BTW, L7 is rated for 400mA only. Also, there is typically no need to put a CMC on the USB supply rails.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for feedback.  putting 100u electrolitic tantalum  in pi filter occupies to much space in my pcb. What about one 10u and one tantalum 100u. Dont know if the filter is unbalanced there is any problems. Also for CMC on the VBUS i try to eliminate the noise in the cable for EMI improvements.  So, you say that i should not fear about this type of connection?